# Set textfield key to jsp variable and apply it to sql query

Tags: java, jsp

I have a jsp which displays customer's information

```
<s:textfield key="customer.firstname" required="true" readonly="true"/>
<s:textfield key="customer.lastname" required="true" readonly="true"/>
<s:textfield key="customer.loginid" required="true"  readonly="true"/>
<s:textfield key="customer.telephone" required="true"  readonly="true"/>
```

I tried this

```
  <c:set var = "customer_loginid" scope = "session" value = "${customer.loginid}"/>
  <c:out value = "${customer_loginid}"/>
```

It can show the value by variable.

Then I would like to use it to fetch the data from the database.

```
<%
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl+dbName, userId, 
password);
statement=connection.createStatement();
//String customerLoginid = ${customer_loginid};//It does not allow me to put the variable here
//also tried
//String customerLoginid = {String) ${customer_loginid};//It does not allow me to put the variable here
String customerLoginid = x; //how to put the variable here??

String sql = "select ordered_product from table2 where customerid ='"+customerLoginid+"'"
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql)

while(resultSet.next())
{
   resultSet.getString("ordered_product")
}
resultSet.close();
statement.close();
%>
```

So how can I put `${customer_loginid}` in the sql query in jsp? Grateful for your advice please. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you've already set scope for session

```
<c:set var = "customer_loginid" scope = "session" value = "${customer.loginid}"/>
```

you can get the value simply.

```
  String customerLoginid = session.getAttribute("customer_loginid");
```